# Ubuntu 14.04 can't mount exFAT external hard disk

Tags: 14.04, mount, exfat

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 lately and tried to read files from an external drive that was formatted to `exFAT` from `NTFS`. I followed a lot of instructions online and got both `exFAT-fuse` and `exFAT-untils` installed but still wasn't able to see the hard drive in my system or manually mount it. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1058:1021 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 2TB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The way I tried to mount it:

```
sudo mkdir /media/elements
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb/media/elements
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1/media/elements
```

and it had the same output:

```
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
       mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
       mount device             : mount device at the known place
       mount directory          : mount known device here
       mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
       mount --bind olddir newdir
or move a subtree:
       mount --move olddir newdir
One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-shared dir
       mount --make-slave dir
       mount --make-private dir
       mount --make-unbindable dir
One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
containig the directory dir:
       mount --make-rshared dir
       mount --make-rslave dir
       mount --make-rprivate dir
       mount --make-runbindable dir
A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
```

---

```
$ dmesg:
```

The result was so long that I couldn't paste it on here. So I put it up on pastebin along with a link to this question.

```
$ fdisk -l:


WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't   support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3f7852a4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500299395072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930272256 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0f68f3b5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           2  2930272255  1465136127    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: paste the result [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post its link to body of your question. thanks

Answer (score 9):

Test this:

Open a terminal.  **(Ctrl+Alt+T)**.

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get update
# apt-get install --reinstall exfat-fuse exfat-utils 
# mkdir /media/user/exfat
# chmod -Rf 777 /media/user/exfat
# fdisk -l
%%Assuming the external drive partition is /dev/sdb1
# mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/user/exfat
```

Replace the `/dev/sdb1` with the exact file path to your external hard drive partition.

To unmount the exFAT external drive:

```
$ sudo -i
# umount /media/user/exfat
```

Comment: Isn't the path to external hard drive usually /media/<hard_drive_name>? So if I replace /dev/sdb1 with the exact file in your example, I'll have /media/user/exfat/media/user/exfat?

Comment: For the last two versions, ubuntu mount external drives to /media/user/. You can mount them anywhere, are the usual /mnt and /media. The important thing is to create the directory and permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your `mount` command is wrong. That's why it complains and shows you a "Usage" message. Try:

```
mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/elements
```

Note the space character between the last two arguments.